# GPU capabilities

Tags: linux, chromebook, arm

The specs for the [KB3288](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockchip_RK3288#Introduction) state that it can decode 2160@24fps H.264 video.

What I'm taking away from this is that this computer can play any 2160 H.264 video at 24fps, which doesn't really make sense to me because I thought that the capabilities of a GPU to play something were directly related to how much data it has to go through. This is dictated by the frame rate, resolution, **and** bitrate.

What is the limiting factor here? What dictates how well a video will play?

Comment: The bit-rate of the compressed, encoded video should never be a problem for a GPU.  The bit-rate is more of a concern during the*transmission* of the video, not when it's being decoded.  It's the uncompressed, decoded output at full resolution and frame rate that can tax the bandwidth of the GPU.

Comment: Thanks. Want to put that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit-rate of the compressed, encoded video should never be a problem for a GPU. The bit-rate is more of a concern during the *transmission* of the video, not when it's being decoded.

It's the uncompressed, decoded output at full resolution and frame rate that can tax the bandwidth of the GPU.  The bit-rate of this output is much greater than the input bit-rate (that's why lossy video codecs were developed), and is more usefully expressed as resolution at a frame-rate than bits-per-second.